# How to customize the downloading path in the following script?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across the script below to download HTML form inputs to the local drive, which works properly. However, I wonder if it is possible to specify the downloading folder? I tried commenting out the `if else` part and add `newLink.href = 'H:\Documents\';` but it didn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" 
             value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
    let saveFile = () => {
      // Get the data from each element on the form.
      const name = document.getElementById('txtName');

      // This variable stores all the data.
      let data = 
          '\r Name: ' + name.value;

      // Convert the text to BLOB.
      const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
      const sFileName = 'formData.txt';    // The file to save the data.

      let newLink = document.createElement("a");
      newLink.download = sFileName;

      if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
      }
      else {
        newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        newLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(newLink);
      }

      newLink.click(); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You switch the href of an element to download a file from another folder on your computer and it do not work? You can specify a subfolder to download. An example href="img/cat.png".